# Perl Server Side Cross domain detection

Tags: perl, apache, cross-domain, mod-perl

I am writing a perl server script.  In my script i want to detect if the the request was made from a web page outside of my websites domain.  For instance, if someone clicks a link that points to my script on blog or from google, i want to detect that and handle it differently than someone making a request to my script from my own webpage.  I have access to a mod perl apache object, but reading through the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~gozer/mod_perl-1.31/Apache/Apache.pm) i'm not sure if that has the facility to do what i need.  Can anyone tell me how to detect this?

Answer (score 5):

On the server side, the only way you can do this is to use the [HTTP Referer header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer). Browsers are normally configured to send this header and to not lie about the referer, but you should be aware that the referer can be trivially spoofed by anybody who wants to do so.